# Automatically create title from a given text

Tags: python, text-processing

I am trying to write a program that will give an apt title when an article is give ( usually an abstract). Is there any standard algorithm available?

Comment: Ask the original author what the title is? :-) I think you're asking an AI-hard problem here.

Comment: Please clarify what exactly you are trying to accomplish. Are you thinking of textually or linguistically analyzing the article text and creating a title for it?

Comment: @Raku Textually analyzing the article ( abstract)

Comment: Published articles will usually have a title already, why not use that?  For unpublished articles, I'd think you're on your own if they don't come with a title.

Comment: In Python 3: `input('Enter apt title here: ')`. Otherwise, `raw_input('Enter apt title here: ')`. Of course, if you're going as far as trying to generate a title, you may as well generate the entire paper. http://www.scielo.cl/scielo.php?script=sci_arttext&pid=S0718-09342006000300001&lng=en&nrm=iso&ignore=.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to do it by hand, you'd have to start with something like word frequency counting, then analyzing phrases that appear a lot or words that appear around each other. I have only briefly touched this topic in Java, but there seems to be a good book for Python that deals with text analysis:

[Text Processing in Python](http://gnosis.cx/TPiP/)

[OpenFTS](http://openfts.sourceforge.net/), an open full text search engine has a Python interface, called [PyFTS].[3](http://rhodesmill.org/brandon/projects/pyfts.html)

Check it out. Maybe that's what you want.